# imap.search setting date parameter as a variable

Tags: ruby, variables, date

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.domain.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'user', 'pass')
imap.examine('INBOX')
puts "Since when? Please in DD-MM-YYYY Format."
@since_date = gets()
mail_count = imap.search(["SINCE", @since_date])
puts "\n  Total Emails Since" + @since_date + mail_count.count.to_s
```

Getting an error here. All I'm trying to do is let the date parameter be set by the user. And then it tells you how many emails since the date. This works if I manually enter a date, but I think I'm declaring the variable incorrectly. Brand new to Ruby and coding, sorry if dumb question.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error in IMAP command SEARCH: Invalid search date parameter (Net::IMAP::BadResponseError)

Comment: Try `gets.chomp` in stead of `gets()` on the `@since_date` line

Comment: thank you, that works. now if only I could figure out why. nevermind, got it. Chomp deletes the new line!

Comment: Posted a bit of an explanation in my answer... if you would be so kind as to accept it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets` returns a string with the carriage return at the end and `chomp` strips that CR off. That is why `gets.chomp` works for you.